# ggridges with heights scaled to counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

How do I change the scaling of a `ggridges` figure so that the plot behaves more like a histogram, and less like a kernel density plot? That is, I would like the figure to reflect the disparate size of the categorical variable.

For instance

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

data(mpg)    

mpg %>% 
  mutate(
    drv = drv %>% 
      fct_reorder(
        cty
        )
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(cty, drv)
    ) +
  geom_density_ridges(
    stat = "binline", 
    scale = .8
    )
```

[image]

the issue here is that the `r` category of `mpg$drv` has only 25 observations, while both  `f` and `4` have over 100 observations each. I want the height of the figure to reflect the count of observations at each point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funny enough, your title is essentially the solution.  You will want to include the `height = ..count..` in your `aes()`

```
mpg %>% 
  mutate(
    drv = drv %>% 
      fct_reorder(
        cty
      )
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(cty, drv, height = ..count..)
  ) +
  geom_density_ridges(
    stat = "binline", 
    scale = .8
  )
```

Which gives you the following:
[image: unscaled height ggpridges]

Comment: I was going to ask a separate question for this, but is it possible to somehow include a secondary y-axis that shows the count values for each of the different values of drv? Perhaps on the right side?